# How to add and delete a row in react-table plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-table

```
<ReactTable
    data={tableData.Revenue_Variable_Cost_Tier_3}
    columns={tier_3}
    defaultPageSize={3}
    showPaginationBottom={false}>
</ReactTable>
```

For example, if it has three rows, how can I add or delete any row?